# Как показать текст в зависимости от data в checkbox?Jquery

Tags: jquery, checkbox

Подскажите, как при выбранном *checkbox*, скрывать/показывать ссылки в `.price-problem`, с привязкой?

Выбрано может быть несколько чекбоксов, соответственно нужно показывать все выбранные и скрывать все невыбранные. Привязка идет в *data*. Типы и проблемы тоже должны быть связаны.

К примеру, выбираем "Не стирает, мигает" - скрываются в `.price-problem` "Течет", остальные показываются.

```html
<div class="remont">
<div class="problem">
<input data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Не стирает" type="checkbox" value="Не стирает">
<input data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Мигает" type="checkbox" value="Мигает">
<input data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Течет" type="checkbox" value="Течет">
</div>

<div class="price-problem">
<a data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Не стирает" href="#" class="price__item">100р</a>
<a data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Мигает" href="#" class="price__item">100р</a>
<a data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Течет" href="#" class="price__item">100р</a>
</div>

</div>
```

---

Всем огромное спасибо! Все варианты рабочие.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю как-то так

```js
$(".problem input").on('change', function(){
  let dataProblem = $(this).attr('data-problem');
  let control = $(`.price-problem a[data-problem="${dataProblem}"]`);
  if (control.is(":hidden")) {
    $(`.price-problem a[data-problem="${dataProblem}"]`).show();
  } else {
    $(`.price-problem a[data-problem="${dataProblem}"]`).hide();
  }
});

[...$(".price-problem a")].forEach(item => $(item).hide())
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="remont">
<div class="problem">
<input data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Не стирает" type="checkbox" value="Не стирает"> - Не стирает
<input data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Мигает" type="checkbox" value="Мигает"> - Мигает
<input data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Течет" type="checkbox" value="Течет"> - Течет
</div>

<div class="price-problem">
<a data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Не стирает" href="#" class="price__item">Не стирает - 100р</a>
<br/>
<a data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Мигает" href="#" class="price__item">Мигает - 100р</a>
<br/>
<a data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Течет" href="#" class="price__item">Течет - 100р</a>
</div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Вариант на **jQuery**.

Привязка идёт по `data-type` (ищется `a[data-type]`) и по `value` (`a[data-problem]`).
Из минусов - [регистрозависимость](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D1%83%D0%B2%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%BA_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B3%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D1%83_%D1%81%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2).

```js
let list = $('.price-problem');

$('.problem').on('click', 'input[type="checkbox"]', function() {
  let inputs = $('.problem').find('input[type="checkbox"]:checked');
  if(inputs.length > 0) {
    list.find('a.--show').removeClass('--show');
    inputs.each(function() {
      let type = $(this).attr('data-type'),
        value = $(this).val(),
        check = $(this).prop('checked');
      
      list.find('a[data-type="'+type+'"][data-problem="'+value+'"]').addClass('--show');
    });
  } else list.find('a.--show').removeClass('--show');
});
```

```css
.price-problem > a {display: none;}

.price-problem > a.--show {display: block;}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="remont">
  <div class="problem">
    <input data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Не стирает" type="checkbox" value="Не стирает"> Стиральная машина - не стирает<br>
    <input data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Мигает" type="checkbox" value="Мигает"> Стиральная машина - мигает<br>
    <input data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Течет" type="checkbox" value="Течет"> Стиральная машина - течёт<br>
    <input data-type="Микроволновая печь" data-problem="Течет" type="checkbox" value="Не крутится"> Микроволновая печь - не крутится<br>
  </div>

  <div class="price-problem">
    <a data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Не стирает" href="#" class="price__item">Стиральная машина - не стирает | 100р</a>
    <a data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Мигает" href="#" class="price__item">Стиральная машина - мигает | 100р</a>
    <a data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Течет" href="#" class="price__item">Стиральная машина - течёт | 100р</a>
    <a data-type="Микроволновая печь" data-problem="Не крутится" href="#" class="price__item">Микроволновая печь - не крутится | 100р</a>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Еще вопрос. А как скрыть дубли? Выбираем "Не стирает, Мигает". Появиться дубли, 2 раза "Не стирает". Вот как в таком случае скрыть дубли при двойном checkbox?

```
<div class="remont">
<div class="problem">
<input data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Не стирает" type="checkbox" value="Не стирает">
<input data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Мигает" type="checkbox" value="Мигает">


</div>

<div class="price-problem">
<a data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Не стирает" href="#" class="price__item">Не стирает</a>
<a data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Мигает" href="#" class="price__item">Не стирает</a>
<a data-type="Стиральная машина" data-problem="Течет" href="#" class="price__item">Течет</a>

</div>
```

Comment: про дубли ничего не было изначально, поэтому код отвечает на вопрос. Другая проблема - другой вопрос - другие ответы. Забрали "галочку" - значит, Вам мой ответ не подходит - удаляю свой ответ.

Comment: верните, поставлю вам галочку - без проблем.